# Use function result inside a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have in oracle a simple select statement (example):

```
SELECT * FROM organisation WHERE ID=15
```

This returns a row :

```
 **ID   | NAME   |   NOTES      | VALUE**
   15   | BEST   | Just Notes...|  112
```

Now I want to take the Value (112) and use it as a parameter in an oracle function :

```
function get_session_text (
     in_value in number
     )
```

return varchar2 is....

So I would like to build a select statement that it will return something like that:

```
 **ID   | NAME   |   NOTES      | VALUE  |  TEXT **  
   15   | BEST   |Just Notes... |  112   | function's result
```

Select * from

I tried to build it but I am not familiar with functions, so could you please help me with that SQL statement?

Comment: @DavidAldridge : Actually something similar with Justin's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       notes,
       value,
       get_session_text( value )
  FROM organization
```

should do it.